# Java Web com Primefaces e Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, aplicação-web, primefaces, dialog

Estou com problemas no Dialog do PrimeFaces. Possuo um Dialog que irá aparecer ao clicar em um commandButton, no método oncomplete, de uma dataTable. Este Dialog irá ter outro dataTable que também terá um outro botão para abrir mais um dialog, desta vez com outro dataTable e nada mais.
Meu problema é, o primeiro Dialog não puxa os objetos corretamente, como pode ver no código, o botão chama o método no actionListener mas o dialog parece que abre antes de executar o actionListener e abre com os objetos ainda vazios.

```
package com.sysnutriweb.bean;
```

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.sysnutriweb.dao.AlimentoXDietaDAO;
import com.sysnutriweb.dao.DietaDAO;
import com.sysnutriweb.domain.Alimento;
import com.sysnutriweb.domain.AlimentoXDieta;
import com.sysnutriweb.domain.Dieta;

@Named(value = "MBDiet")
@ManagedBean(name = "MBDiet")
@SessionScoped
public class DietaBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List listDiets;
    private Dieta diet = new Dieta();
    private DietaDAO dDao;
    private List foods = new ArrayList<>();
    private Alimento food;

```
private String flagS = "V-";

@PostConstruct
public void begin() {
    dDao = new DietaDAO();
    listDiets = dDao.loadAll();
    flagS += "B-";
}

//@PostConstruct
public void getDietSelected(ActionEvent e) {
    diet = (Dieta) e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("selectedDiet");
    System.out.println("Diet: " + diet.toString());
    List<AlimentoXDieta> axd = new AlimentoXDietaDAO().loadAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < axd.size(); i++) {
        if (axd.get(i).getDietId().getId() == diet.getId())
            foods.add(axd.get(i));
    }
    flagS+="S-";
    System.out.println("Called: " + foods.size() + "\nFlagS: " + flagS);
}

public void getFoodSelected(ActionEvent e) {
    food = (Alimento) e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("selectedFood");
}
```

//Getters Setters
}

E aqui a parte problemática do meu XHTML.

```
                <p:column headerText="Descrição da dieta" id="descricao">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{diet.descricaoDieta}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Ações" id="acoes" width="10%">
                    <center>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-info" id="btnInfo" update="@form"
                            actionListener="#{MBDiet.getDietSelected}"
                            oncomplete="PF('dlgFoods').show()" ajax="true">
                            <f:attribute name="selectedDiet" value="#{diet}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:tooltip id="toolTipBtnInfo" for="btnInfo"
                            value="Clique para ver os alimentos presentes nesta dieta"
                            position="top" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
```

Esta parte do código chama o dialog descrito aqui

```
<!--  Diet info -->
<p:dialog
    header="Alimentos na dieta #{MBDiet.flagS} #{MBDiet.diet.nomeDieta}"
    widgetVar="dlgFoods" modal="true" showEffect="explode"
    resizable="false" draggable="false" appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:form id="formInfoTable">
        <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum dado cadastrado!" paginator="true"
            id="tbFoodsDiet" value="#{MBDiet.foods}" var="food">
            <p:column headerText="Nome" id="nome" width="10px">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{food.foodId.nome}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Hora para consumir" id="descricao" width="40%">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{food.hora}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Ações" id="acoes" width="10%">
                <center>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-info" id="btnInfo"
                        update=":formInfo" actionListener="#{MBDiet.getFoodSelected}"
                        oncomplete="PF('dlgFoodInfo').show()">
                        <f:attribute name="selectedFood" value="#{food}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:tooltip id="toolTipBtnInfo" for="btnInfo"
                        value="Clique para ver os detalhes deste alimento" position="top" />
                </center>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Que logo após chamará este dialog

```
<!--  Food info -->
<p:dialog header="Alimento #{MBDiet.food.nome}" widgetVar="dlgFoodInfo"
    modal="true" showEffect="fade" height="100" resizable="false" id="dlgFoodInfo"
    draggable="true" appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:form id="formInfo">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Nome:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.nome}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Açucares:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.acucares}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Cálcio:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.calcio}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Calorias:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.calorias}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Carboidratos:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.carboidratos}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Colesterol:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.colesterol}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Ferro:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.ferro}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Fibras:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.fibras}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Gorduras:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.gorduras}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Insaturadas:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.insaturadas}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="pootássio:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.potassio}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Proteínas:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.proteinas}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Saturadas:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.saturadas}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Trans:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.trans}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Vitamina A:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.vitaminaA}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Vitamina C:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.vitaminaC}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Vitamina D:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.vitaminaD}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:separator />
        <p:outputLabel value="Informações especiais" />
        <p:separator />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Data de cadastro:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.dtCad}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Identificação:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{MBDiet.food.id}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Caso prefiram, deixarei o link do github e peço desculpas, esta é minha primeira pergunta!
Desde já, obrigado a todos!
Link: https://github.com/SakamotoLfe/SysNutriWebV0

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Alfredo. Sempre poste o código diretamente na pergunta, porque no futuro se o link quebrar a sua pergunta não terá mais utilidade. Você pode até colocar um link para o código completo no GitHub, mas coloque no corpo da pergunta pelo menos o trecho problemático. Sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Alfredo, lamentavelmente ninguém irá navegar pelo seu projeto em busca do seu problema e com certeza você não obterá a ajuda que necessita, além de ter sua pergunta fechada pela moderação. O usual é você editar sua pergunta e colocar nela o trecho de código problemático, apontando o que já tentou fazer para solucionar o problema e indicando o erro (a _exception_ ou a mensagem de erro) que aconteceu.

Comment: Alfredo o objetivo aqui não é ensinar todo um conteúdo e sim tirar dúvidas, poste o trecho que vc está com dúvidas. Seja bem vindo à comunidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o erro. Na verdade estava tudo funcionando corretamente, apenas o Dialog que não exibia os dados que eu desejava em seu Header. Após alterar o Update do CommandButton tudo funcionou normalmente!